How to let return type depend on relations included in Prisma object
How can I create a function that takes in a Prisma object and let the return type be based on the included relations?
My goal is that versionWithRelations is typed as having the properties pages, variables, and actions, while versionWithoutRelations does not.
Here is my current attempt:
import { Prisma } from "@prisma/client";

const getVersion = <
  Relations extends Prisma.AppVersionInclude,
  App extends Prisma.AppGetPayload<{
    include: { versions: { include: Relations } };
  }>,
>(
  app: App,
): Prisma.AppVersionGetPayload<{ include: Relations }> => {
  return app.versions[0]!;
};

const withRelations = await prisma.app.findUnique({
  where: { id: "foo" },
  include: {
    versions: {
      include: {
        pages: true,
        variables: true,
        actions: true,
      },
    },
  },
});

const withoutRelations = await prisma.app.findUnique({
  where: { id: "foo" },
  include: {
    versions: true,
  },
});
const versionWithRelations = getVersion(withRelations!);
const versionWithoutRelations = getVersion(withoutRelations!);

// Here are the types I expect:
// typeof versionWithRelations
type VersionWithRelations = {
  id: string;
  appId: string;
  majorVersion: number;
  minorVersion: number;
  patchVersion: number;
  pages: {
    id: string;
    appVersionId: string;
    path: string;
    description: string;
  }[];
  variables: {
    id: string;
    appVersionId: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;
  }[];
  actions: {
    id: string;
    appVersionId: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;
  }[];
}

// typeof versionWithoutRelations
type VersionWithoutRelations = {
  id: string;
  appId: string;
  majorVersion: number;
  minorVersion: number;
  patchVersion: number;
}

Here is my Prisma schema:

model App {
  id       String       @id @default(cuid())
  name     String
  versions AppVersion[]
}

model AppVersion {
  id           String        @id @default(cuid())
  appId        String
  majorVersion Int
  minorVersion Int
  patchVersion Int
  pages        AppPage[]
  variables    AppVariable[]
  actions      AppAction[]

  app App @relation(fields: [appId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@unique([appId, majorVersion, minorVersion, patchVersion])
}

model AppPage {
  id           String @id @default(cuid())
  appVersionId String
  path         String
  description  String

  appVersion AppVersion @relation(fields: [appVersionId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@unique([appVersionId, path])
}

model AppVariable {
  id           String @id @default(cuid())
  appVersionId String
  name         String
  description  String

  appVersion AppVersion @relation(fields: [appVersionId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@unique([appVersionId, name])
}

model AppAction {
  id           String @id @default(cuid())
  appVersionId String
  name         String
  description  String

  appVersion AppVersion @relation(fields: [appVersionId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@unique([appVersionId, name])
}


I'm a bit confused on what you actually need - are pages, variables, and actions other relational models? Can you include your Prisma schema and the TypeScript type you hope to emit?

Thank you, @SheaHunterBelsky. I've updated the question with the Prisma schema and TypeScript types.

are you looking to get an instance of the app model which contains all related versions? Or do you only want the AppVersion entries that correspond to the specific appId of your choice?

If I understand correctly, you want to find AppVersion entries whose appId value corresponds to a specific value. Why not use prisma.appVersion.findMany based on the appId you need?
const versionWithRelations = await prisma.appVersion.findMany({
  include: {
    pages: true,
    variables: true,
    actions: true,
  },
  where: {
    appId: "foo"
  }
});

const versionWithoutRelations = await prisma.appVersion.findMany({
  where: {
    appId: "foo"
  }
});


Thanks, but that's not really what I want to achieve. What I want to do is create a generic function so that the return type of that function depends on the relations included in the argument passed to the function. That way I can use the function on any App, and retain type safety on the return value. The getVersion function is just a simple example of such a function.
